# How to hide a table row which have TD containing certain values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a SharePoint web site , and I need using CSS (Preferred) or JavaScript, to hide a table row that have two main TDs:-

1. TD with a text named Item Number.
2. TD with an input titled Item number.

Here is how the mark-up is constructed:-

[image]

Can anyone advice on this please?

i tried the following script , but did not hide the Item Number or the customer initial , baring in mind that all the TR are inside a table which have .ms-formtable class:-

```
    <script>
$(function() {

  $('.ms-formtable tr').each(function() {
    var frstVal = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
    if (frstVal.match(/Item Number|customer Initials/i)) {
      $(frstVal).remove()
    }
  });

});

    </script>
```

here is the related markup :-

```
<table width="100%" class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="113" class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader">

<nobr>Item Number</nobr>

</h3></td>


<td width="350" class="ms-formbody" valign="top">

<span dir="none"><input title="Item Number" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" id="_x0049_D1_806a702b-1716-47f5-a93c-16067f502daf_$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""><br></span>

<span class="ms-metadata">Do not customize at the list level</span>


</td></tr>
```

**EDIT**

now i tried this script :-

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $('.ms-formtable table').each(function () {
        $(this).find('tr').each(function () {
                   $(this).find('td').text() = 'Item Number';
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });

    });


</script>
```

but did not hide the Item Number field...

Comment: @Jayababu i provided the related markups. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your script and HTML has a few issues.

In your html there is no text inside any of the `td's` and you have the following query :

```
var frstVal = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(); // how is this query going to retrive anything at all ?
```

The issue with your script is you're iterating over all the `tr's` but you're caching only the text() of the first `td` inside every `tr`, so change the script to the following :

```
$(function() {

  $('.ms-formtable tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        var str_text = $(this).text();
        if (str_text.match(/Item Number|customer Initials/i)) {
          $(this).text(' ');
        } 
    });

  });
});
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dpc9wxpa/)**

### Edit

You're selecting the wrong element, the below query is wrong :

```
var str_text = $(this).text();
```

`$(this)` is pointing to `tr` , you need to go inside `tr` and find `nobr` and then perform your action.

```
$('.ms-formtable table').each(function () {
    $(this).find('tr').each(function () {
               var str_text = $(this).find('td nobr').text();
               // console.log(str_text);
               if (str_text.match(/Item Number/i)) {
                 $(this).find('input').remove(); // add this to remove input
                 $(this).text(' ');
               } 
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: @johnG sorry in my code , i forgot to add a bracket at the ending `});` see this example , and you'll understand http://jsfiddle.net/dpc9wxpa/

Comment: your script will just remove the label "Item Number" but the input field will still there !!

Comment: @johnG inside the if statement add an additional rule `$(this).find('input').remove();` . FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/dpc9wxpa/

Comment: so this will only clear the label,, so how i can remove the input field also ?

Comment: i tried the following :-<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

                             
    $('.ms-formtable table').each(function () {
    $(this).find('tr').each(function () {
               var str_text = $(this).find('td nobr').text();
               // console.log(str_text);
               if (str_text == 'Item Number') {
               $(this).hide();    
               } 
        
    });

});   

});
</script> but did not hide any thing//

Comment: @johnG edited just add this line inside if $(this).find('input').remove(); , your above code is wrong !

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for .

```js
$('tr').each(function(){
  var count=0;
$(this).find('td').each(function(){
if($(this).text()=='Item Number'){count=count+1;}
if($(this).find('input[title="Item Number"]')){count=count+1;}
});
if(count==2){$(this).hide();}

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="113" class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader">

<nobr>Item Number</nobr>

</h3></td>


<td width="350" class="ms-formbody" valign="top">

<span dir="none"><input title="Item Number" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" id="_x0049_D1_806a702b-1716-47f5-a93c-16067f502daf_$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""><br></span>

<span class="ms-metadata">Do not customize at the list level</span>


</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Code snippet output will be an empty page,as in example table is having only one row which has 2 td's as mentioned,so am hiding the row,based on the creteria.

Comment: i tried you script inside my form but did not hide the Item Number , still the label and the inout field are showing..

Comment: the code which you have posted above is missing tr inside the table.So Just check whether you have a tr in your original code or not.If not add tr and try

Comment: now i moved your code to be loaded after the form and it hide the whole table not just the related TR..

Comment: It will only hide the tr not the table,just check if any other code in your local is affecting this.As per my code this attribute will only refer the tr not the table.
In My code i have only one row in the table,even though its only hiding the tr,it appeared like as if its hiding the whole table.

Comment: table is having only one row in my example so add some more rows to the code and try ,you can see the remaining rows as it is.